# Gulp using wiredep for bower dependencies: output different path

Tags: javascript, gulp, wiredep

I'm using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep). The output I get is not the right path to my files. I'd like to change the output of that path accordingly.

Current path:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Wanted outcome:

```
<script src="./vendors/angular.js"></script>
```

Current gulp task:

```
gulp.task('index', function() {
  var target = gulp.src(files.app_files.target);
  var sources = gulp.src(files.app_files.sources, {
    read: false
  });
  // {caseSensitive: true }

  return target
    .pipe(inject(sources, {
      ignorePath: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wiredep is born to wire bower dependencies in your html.

Anyway you can set a programmatica acces to js like this

```
Programmatic Access
You can run wiredep without manipulating any files.

require('wiredep')();
...returns...

{
  js: [
    'paths/to/your/js/files.js',
    'in/their/order/of/dependency.js'
  ],
  css: [
    'paths/to/your/css/files.css'
  ],
  // etc. 
}
```

as you can find in the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep#programmatic-access)

As advice, in dev phase there is nothing wrong using bower_dependencies as your "repo". In build phase, when you prepare for prduction environment you can use [useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) in combination with wiredep and then move your builded file where you want it

Comment: thanks for the advice much appreciated. you are right, it is okay to have it setup this way for development. hypothetically, distribution times comes along. Is there no way to stamp these out as a specific path output?

Comment: wiredep read from a path. You need something else to stamp out. useref works like this. this https://github.com/rixlabs/statbriks/blob/master/gulpfile.js is the gulpfile of one of my projects I use both plugins

Comment: I'll try useref right now if it works I'll let you know in a bit